# Laravel: Too few arguments to function Vonage\Client::Vonage\{closure}(), 4 passed and exactly 5 expected

Tags: vonage

I am trying to make a sms notification using nexmo. I dont know what it means Too few arguments to function Vonage\Client::Vonage{closure}(), 4 passed and exactly 5 expected. I was trying to search for the error and it said the error is in line 145 from folder vendor\nexmo\client-core\src\Client.php on line 145[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvFnM.png)

Comment: Could you please post the code? The code you posted doesn't seem relevant as it looks like the error handling code of the library.

Comment: Have you found something about this? I'm having a similiar trouble